# Multiplicative groups modulo $p$, $p$ prime, with orders other than $p^n-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Multiplicative groups modulo $p$, for certain classes of primes, can be constructed to my knowledge from the following sets with straightforward group operations:

$\mathbb{Z}_p$, with standard multiplication $\mod p$ as the operation,

$a+b\sqrt{2}, a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_p$, with $(a+b\sqrt{2})(c+d\sqrt{2})=(ac+{2}bd \bmod p)+\sqrt{2}(ad+bc \bmod p)$ as the operation,

$a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{2^2},a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}_p$, with such an operation,

and so on. Since $0$, $(0,0)$, $(0,0,0)$, and so on, respectively, are not elements of the group for the common group operations, the sizes of the groups are $p-1$, $p^2-1$, $p^3-1$, and so on.

*Obviously, one can make groups of multiples of these orders, e.g. $p(p+1)(p-1)^2$. Additionally, some clear subgroup orders are present, such as the group of quadratic nonresidues in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ having order $(p-1)/2$.*
**Apart from such cases**, is it possible to construct other multiplicative groups modulo $p$ with different sizes? Specifically, what are the group operations that make this possible if so? Examples would be appreciated if possible. If not possible, why not?

E.g. The size of a group given by the set of unordered pairs $\{a,b\},$ $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_p,a\neq b$ would have size $1/2(n)(n-1)$, but is there a possible group operation for this set?

Edit: I mean "multiplicative groups" in the sense that there is a "$0$" element of the set that is not included in the group.

Edit2: This question is not on a specific group operation, but rather whether there exists ANY group operation that allows one to construct a "$\mod p$" group of a different size.

Comment: Is the group operation "addition" or "multiplication"? Can you give an example to show how the group operation works?

Comment: What quasi said. What exactly is the group operation for entities like $a+bi$ or $a+bi+cj$?

Comment: Will edit question

Comment: How are you defining $ij$?

Comment: I left them as placeholders for different things that could go there, edited now to a specific example - $\sqrt{2}$. Note that it is not really important for this post what they are because they are just examples, not directly related to my main question in this post.

Comment: You don't always get a group with $\sqrt{2}$. When $p=7$ you have
$$(3+\sqrt{2})(3-\sqrt{2})=3^2-(\sqrt2)^2=7=0.$$You probably want to study finite fields.

Comment: Again, just an example of groups that work for some primes p. Instead of $\sqrt{2}$ I could utilize $\sqrt{a}$ where $a$ is a quadratic nonresidue modulo $p$. Im trying to keep the initial examples uncomplicated as to not distract from the question.

Comment: Ok. The next suggestions would be the group of quadratic residues. It has size $(p-1)/2$. Non-zero squares in $\Bbb{Z}_p[\sqrt m]$, $m$ a quadratic non-residue, have $(p^2-1)/2$ elements etc. How about the group of invertible 2x2 matrices with entries in $\Bbb{Z}_p$? It has $p(p-1)^2(p+1)$ elements.

Comment: Or may be the product $(x_0,x_1)\cdot(y_0,y_1)=(x_0y_0,x_1y_0+x_0y_1)$ of pairs with the zeroth component non-zero. $(1,0)$ is the neutral element and we have $p(p-1)$ elements. This is a cyclic group though. What exactly do you want this for? We can get any finite abelian group as a subgroup of a cartesian product of multiplicative groups of finite fields, so I'm not sure what to aim at?

Comment: As stated in the question, I am looking for orders that are not multiples of already known orders: p, (p-1), and (p+1) are all present above. I will edit the question again to specify that I am also not looking for orders that are trivially the orders of a subgroup of one of the groups present. Thank you for the suggestions, these type of answers are precisely what Im looking for, just an order that is **not** a multiple of those present or a clear subgroup order of one of them.

Comment: If you exclude the orders of subgroups, then you have excluded **all** possible orders. What do you want? Elliptic curves over $\Bbb{Z}_p$ will also give you groups of "random" order (in a range around $p+1$) with an operation defined in terms of arithmetic modulo $p$.

Comment: I meant only to exclude the order of the subgroups I can easily determine from groups mentioned in the question. Your mention of elliptic curves here I think may give me what I want -- do you have any resource suggestions for this?

Comment: If, by multiplicative group, you mean the group of units in an algebra over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, then there are other possibilities. For example, invertible matrices are units in the matrix algebra. However, if you want the algebra to be commutative, then the only possibilities are essentially the ones you listed. To go beyond such groups you need to work with things like elliptic curves, etc.

Comment: May you give an example or reference of such a group (invertible matrices)?